# Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 409; Error Code: CNAMEAlreadyExists;

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

How to check which distribution uses CNAME?
I've removed alias from one of my distribution about 3 hours ago.
And then removed the distribution.
However I can only see the error when creation a new one distribution with the alias.

```
aws cloudfront list-distributions | jq '.DistributionList.Items[]
```

shows nothing related to the CNAME

Comment: What's the CNAME that you are trying to assign?

Comment: It's a record in aws route53 hosted zone

Comment: Delete it first and add the CNAME back to r53 **after** CF distribution is created.

Comment: Got it. Removed record from route53. Thanks!